# how to build app container in Python or Matlab

Tags: python, matlab

I have just started learning Python.

I would like to build an application with bar menus and different windows contained inside what I think coders call a 'boiler plate' a window containing everything.

The app has to contain also pull-down menus with file handling, settings, functions .. some are repeated inside windows contained in the boiler plate.

The app would like this
[image]

I started writing the app in Matlab but I could not build the 'container' windows, the boiler plate, pull-down menus all in one app.

Is there a Python package to start with and write something like the screen shot above?

Thanks for time and attention

Comment: pyqt or tkinter

Comment: My feeling is that the epoch of desktop apps was 1990s, and since 2010s it died completely, most new small apps migrating to the web interface (via a web browser), including when the app runs exclusively on a local machine.

Comment: Alex thanks for pointing out the general trend, I agree. But for electronic circuit design and in particular to use the Smith Chart, the tools currently used, I mean tools that companies pay a lot of money, render all useful data on one large screen, like an aircraft cockpit for the pilot or designer avoid wasting time browsing through different tabs, at least for all the key parameters. Thanks anyway for the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple Windows/Frames in Tkinter GUI with Python using tkFrame
https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html